# How do I get git log --follow to respect --skip?

Tags: git

When using `git log --skip=1`, when I use `--follow`, it seems to inhibit `--skip=1`.

1. Why is this happening? Is this by design or a bug?
2. Is there a way to prevent it from doing that?

Comment: Have you tried putting `--follow` before `--skip=1`?

Comment: @JustinPearce: I hadn't, but now I have, and it makes no difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear whether this is "bug" or "feature".

It's not true that `--follow` *inhibits* `--skip`.  The issue is more fundamental and has to do with the way `git log` works.

Like any Git command that traverses the commit graph, `git log` must *walk* the graph, one commit at a time.  It does so using a priority queue that can contain any number (including zero) of commits.

The priority queue simply holds the commit hash IDs.  When you run:

```
git log <arguments> <commit-specifier-A> <commit-specifier-B>
```

(e.g., `git log master develop`), Git translates the given commit-specifiers to hash IDs and enters all those hash IDs into the priority queue.  If you give *no* commit specifiers, Git looks up the hash ID of `HEAD` and puts that (single) commit hash into the priority queue.

The `git log` code now enters its main loop, which is:

1. Remove the highest priority commit from the queue.
2. Decide whether this commit is "interesting".  If so, show it (this part is fairly complicated).
3. Using this commit, find its parent commit(s).  Using any modifiers specified on the command line (such as `--no-walk` or `--first-parent`), put the appropriate set of such parent hashes into the priority queue (provided they have not already been visited and/or are not already there).
4. Repeat until the priority queue is empty.

The `--skip` operation affects step 2: if the skip count is nonzero, `git log` decrements the skip count and moves on to step 3, so that the commit does not get shown.  In effect, the commit is "uninteresting" (but the skip count decrements).  Once the skip count reaches zero, no commits are skipped: all go into the "is this commit interesting" test.

Additional log options, such as those for History Simplification or—the one you're concerned with here—the `--follow` option, also affect step 2, but only after the `skip > 0` test: the commit is only interesting if it meets some criteria.

For `--follow`, the criterion (singular) is whether the (single) file path name that Git is checking is to be produced by a diff between the commit's parent and the commit.  This question is much easier to answer for ordinary (non-merge) commits, which have only one parent, than it is for merge commits.  However, the main point here is that the "show or skip this commit based on `--follow`" test occurs *after* the test-and-decrement of the skip count, rather than before it.

If "test and decrement skip count" test applied *after* the "is this commit interesting" test, it would behave the way I think you want.  But it doesn't, so it doesn't.  For those who want `--skip` to count *commits* rather than *interesting commits*, this is a feature.  For those who want `--skip` to count *interesting commits* rather than *commits*, this is a bug.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately I don't follow (not sure if pun intended). If the only step that involves displaying an item is also responsible for the "test and decrement skip count" operation, then how in the world is it possible for a positive skip count to not skip anything?

Comment: Maybe I should split step 2 into two separate steps? It's done in some order. If the `if (skip && --skip >= 0) continue;` part is *first*, before the `if (interesting(commit))` part, it behaves the way we observe.

Comment: The only way I can understand your explanation is if I explain it as follows (again not sure if pun intended :P): *Let's assume a linear history for illustration. When you don't use `--follow`, `--skip` refers to the number of commits **involving that file** whose displaying should be skipped. But when you use `--follow`, the behavior is changed such that `--skip` refers to the offset of the commit from the top of the history (this is **any** commit, not just those that involve this file) at which traversal begins. This may be a bug or a feature depending on your P.O.V.* ...is this correct?

Comment: But with the behavior as it is now, there's an easy route forward for people who want to count only selected commits: pipe to simple tools like tail.  The other way there'd be no easy route back.  Downsides every direction, judgement call, the downsides to this way are easy to deal with.

Comment: @Mehrdad: it's close enough—except that you'll see this somewhat odd `--skip` behavior for other arguments that inhibit showing some commits as well.

Comment: @jthill: How do you know what number to give `tail` when you aren't using `--oneline` though?

Comment: @torek: I see, thanks. +1 Is it just me is or is there nothing in the documentation to suggest this should be the behavior when `--follow` (or others) are used? Because unless there is, I don't see how it isn't a bug. It literally says *`--follow`: "Continue listing the history of a file beyond renames"*, which in no way allows for the existing behavior before renames to change....

Comment: There is indeed nothing in the documentation about this. That's not the only documentation flaw—the whole priority queue mechanism is very poorly explained. The documentation has gotten a little better in terms of telling what the priorities of `--date-order`, `--author-date-order`, and `--commit-order` are now but are still not good at noting the difference between the committer date and author date (and that `--since`/`--until` only look at committer dates, not author dates).